# How do I test that a text field in $form_state has been populated by the user?

Tags: forms

At the moment I am using the following code.

```
if (!empty($form_state['values']['my-field']) {
  // ...
}
```

If the user has entered 0 (a valid input in my case) my test will return `FALSE`. My guess is that I need to test for an empty string '', but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why you can't set `'#required' = TRUE` ?

Comment: Because there maybe no data for the user to input in some of the fields. I think @kiamlaluno is probably right with is_numeric(). Just need to read up on it and test before I tick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how `empty()` behaves; `empty($value)` returns `FALSE` when `$value` is:

- `NULL`
- 0
- A variable that has not been initialized to any value
- An empty string
- A string containing `"0"`

Since the content of a text field is always a string, you can use the following code, if you are expecting an integer.

```
if (!is_numeric($form_state['values']['my-field'])) {
  // Error: The user didn't enter a number.
}
```

That is the code that Drupal uses to check the user input is a number.
Notice there isn't the need of first passing the user input to `trim()`: `is_numeric("")` or `is_numeric(" ")` returns `FALSE`, while `is_numeric(" 2")` returns `TRUE` and the value of `(integer)" 2"` is 2.

Since [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) accepts also floating point values, to be sure to get only integer values you should use the following code.

```
$value = $form_state['values']['my-field'];

if (is_numeric($value) && ((string)(float)$value) != ((string)(integer)(float)$value)) {
  // It is an integer.
}
```

I would rather use just `is_numeric()` as in the first snippet, though. As long as the user is said to enter an integer, the fact an input like 2e2 is changed to 2 should not matter.

If you want to allow the users to enter a integer as 2e3 (which is 2000, when written without exponential part), when getting the integer entered from the user you should use `(integer)(float)$form_state['values']['my-field']` instead of `(integer)$form_state['values']['my-field']`.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the field in question and what values could possibly be entered into it.

In most cases an empty string would mean that the field has had no value set. 
If zero is a valid value then check like this:

```
if ($form_state['values']['my-field'] !== '')
```

That will check that the value is an empty string, whereas != '' would also match zero and false etc.

Also, depending on your set-up and requirements, if the field has a default value you have to decide what happens in the case the the value in form state equals the default value, because in that case you don't know if the user has left the field default on purpose or not.